# Unable to connect to XAMPP server

Tags: java, sql, xampp

I cannot connect to XAMPP server. Below is the error log. How can I solve this?

```
2019-11-03 16:20:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-11-03 16:20:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-11-03 16:20:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-11-03 16:20:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-11-03 16:20:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-11-03 16:20:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-11-03 16:20:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-11-03 16:20:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300288
2019-11-03 16:20:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active. 
2019-11-03 16:20:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-11-03 16:20:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-11-03 16:20:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically  writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-11-03 16:20:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-11-03 16:20:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-11-03 16:20:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.8 started; log sequence number 300297; transaction id 171
2019-11-03 16:20:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-11-03 16:20:43 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-11-03 16:20:43 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-11-03 16:20:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 191103 16:20:43 InnoDB: using atomic writes.
```

Comment: Do you have also IPv6 on this machine?

Comment: Nope my machine is using IPv4. I solved this finally by reinstall XAMPP but need to save all the important db first before doing so.